# Swift array access triggers EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: random, swift, breakpoints, arc4random

Here is my code (largeAsteroids.count is never 0):

```
var largeAsteroids=[[SKTexture]]()
func randomLargeAsteroidTextures()->Array<SKTexture>{
        let i=Int(arc4random())%largeAsteroids.count
        return largeAsteroids[i]// this line triggers EXC_BREAKPOINT
    }
```

When I execute my code, I receive no errors but I get a EXC_BREAKPOINT. I ensured there wasn't any breakpoint and at index i there was a valid object.
[image]

First I changed SKTexture to AnyObject, it didn't help.
Then I tried to use NSMutableArray instead of swift array, problem still exist:

```
var largeAsteroids=NSMutableArray()
    func randomLargeAsteroidTextures()->AnyObject{
        let i=Int(arc4random())%largeAsteroids.count
        return largeAsteroids.objectAtIndex(i) // this line triggers EXC_BREAKPOINT
    }
```

update:

Problem solved,
replace:

```
let i=Int(arc4random())%largeAsteroids.count
```

by:

```
let i=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(largeAsteroids.count)))
```

Thanks for Matt's solution:

> You should probably be using arc4random_uniform. You'll get modulo bias from your current implementation. –  Matt Gibson

Comment: What does `println("i is \(i), count is \(largeAsteroids.count)")` print?

Comment: func randomLargeAsteroidTextures()->Array<SKTexture>{
        print("??")
        let i=Int(arc4random())%largeAsteroids.count
        println("i is \(i), count is \(largeAsteroids.count)")
        return largeAsteroids[i]
    }
    printed result:
    ??i is 3, count is 7
??i is 5, count is 7
??(lldb) 
    when it crashes, the second print does not execute but EXC_BREAKPOINT pointed to return largeAsteroids[i]

Comment: You should probably be using `arc4random_uniform`. You'll get modulo bias from your current implementation.

Comment: Thank you Matt! I change to 
        let i=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(largeAsteroids.count))), it seems working fine.

Comment: @YongxuRen I've added an answer to explain what was actually causing your problem (your array index was sometimes negative due to an unsigned-to-signed conversion on a 32-bit platform.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were running on a 32-bit target, yes? On a 32-bit target (e.g. iPhone 4), Swift Ints are 32-bits, and signed. However, on any platform, arc4random() returns a 32-bit *unsigned* integer.

Because of this conflict, and your conversion to Int, `Int(arc4random())`, sometimes—in fact, half the time, all else being equal—your number was negative, giving you a negative array index, and causing your problem (though I get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, as I'd expect, when I reproduce the problem; presumably you have a breakpoint set for exceptions?)

My suggestion, to use arc4random_uniform, should work fine as long as the count of your asteroids is never more than Int.max on a 32-bit platform, which is presumably quite unlikely, unless you're giving your gamer a *really* hard time. It will also avoid modulo bias in the random generation, so your resulting random numbers will be more uniformly distributed than in your original solution.

Comment: Yes This is exactly what the problem was. I cleaned all my breakpoints before execution, but I get EXC_BREAKPOINT everytime. I guess it is probably a bug in xcode 6(or swift).

Comment: This happend to me as well. The next morning when I was looking through that code I was like... *facepalm*, "I'm dumb!"